# How can the `to:` and `delivered-to:` fields in an email i received be different?

Tags: email, gmail

I received an email and I noticed that the `Delivered-To:` and `To:` fields were different.  The `To:` field is not my actual email address, but the `Delivered-To:` field is.  How does this happen?

```
Delivered-To: mike.smith@work.com
To: "msmith@work.com" <msmith@work.com>
```

To add to this - I thought there might be some automatic forwarding setup at my office, but I tested sending something to `msmith@work.com` and it didn't come through to me.

Answer (score 14):

Just like snail mail  letters, SMTP email has two different sets of address information: the envelope headers (like the addresses printed on the outside of an envelope) which are used by the SMTP servers to route and deliver the email, and the normal headers, which are part of the mail message and which are only read and interpreted by the user in his mail client/webmail, just like the address attached to a salutation at the start of a physical letter.

Unlike the post office, SMTP usually throws away most of the envelope before it hands the message to the user. I think your `Delivered-To:` header probably reflects the original  `RCPT TO:` header found in the SMTP envelope.

The `To:` header is part of the mail message and your address does not need to be there for the message to get delivered correctly. (As long as your address is in the envelope it gets delivered to you.)

You'll find that the case when among others your email gets forwarded or when your address was on the BCC (blind carbon copy) field.

Comment: Is Delivered-To a standard header? Why does gmail use it instead of X-Delivered-To

Comment: So are you saying that `RCPT TO` is the standard equivalent of `Delivered-To`?

Comment: No. `RCPT TO:` is the SMTP command. `Delivered-To:` *may* be how the SMTP server at the final destination records  to which mailbox the message was sent; after alias expansion, forwards, address rewrites etc.  As far as *I know* there is no standard that mandates/defines it.

Comment: @Pacerier The `Delivered-To` header indeed is non-standard, but implemented in a few widely used unix smtps like qmail and postfix. See here http://www.postfix.org/virtual.8.html  _sorry for being a little late to the party_

Answer (score 2):

If its gmail its possible there is a forward or an alias setup. Also I believe if it has either listed for that users mailbox it could report one or the other.

I would suggest verifying [Forwarding options](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2707558?hl=en) are setup correctly after looking to see if either a forward or an alias are setup.

If you send that message to msmith@work.com and it reported mike.smith@work.com I believe that would mean mike.smith@work.com is the ACTUAL mailbox label.

Let us know!

Comment: So I thought there might be some automatic forwarding at my office, but I tested sending something to `msmith@work.com` and it didn't come through to me.

Answer (score -1):

`To:` is an initial and mandatory email header. Its value is being used by `SMTP` servers in order to properly route your mail.
`Delivery-to:`, in contrast, is not mandatory and is added only when the mail is delivered to mailbox. In some setups this may happen more than once, but usually this is the end of route.
Practically:
 - sender sends mail to `msmith@work.com`
 - through `MX` record it
   reaches your `SMTP` server
 - aliases table on your `SMTP` server has an entry which says

> Forward all mail for `msmith@work.com` to `mike.smith@work.com`

According to this entry, `SMTP` server delivers mail to `mike.smith@work.com` mailbox adding `Delivered-to:` header to the mail or delegates delivery to `POP3/IMAP` server.
There are a lot of ways (except aliases) to change recepient's mailbox name on `STMP` server. This is common practice which brings ease into mail management and migration.

Comment: The receiving SMTP server does not use the `To:` header in the message itself for mail delivery.